# Formulate $\min \dfrac{\|Ax-b\|^2_1}{1-\|x\|_\infty}$ as a SOCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

> Formulate the following problem as a [second-order cone program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_cone_programming) (SOCP). $$ \begin{array}{ll} \underset {x} {\text{minimize}} & \dfrac{\|Ax-b\|^2_1}{1-\|x\|_\infty}\end{array} $$

---

I have this problem and do not know how to solve it. Can anyone please help me or give me guidelines?

Comment: I suppose you have some extra conditions that guarantee $\|x\|_\infty<1$. Anyways, you can write a series of constraints euther linearly or using a second-order cone. For instance: $s\leq 1-\|x\|_\infty$, $u\geq \|Ax-b\|_1$ and $st\geq u^2$ with $s,t\geq 0$ are all expressible this way.

Comment: No I do not have any extra conditions. I asked before too because was looking strange to me too.

Comment: What is the source of this optimization problem?